# Как с помощью java получить значение температуры и загруженности видеокарты

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью java получить значение температуры и загруженности видеокарты.

Answer (score 6):

У каждого производителя карты (вернее GPU) есть свой проприетарный API. У Nvidia [он такой](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf) у ATI [такой](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/graphics-development-sdks/display-library-adl-sdk/)

Интерфейсы этих API на С/С++ так что придется к ним писать [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) интерфейсы из Java.

В частности, для Nvidia прототип вызова функции возвращающей температуры карты (вернее процессора) такой:

```
BOOL CDECL NvCplGetThermalSettings
  (IN UINT nWindowsMonitorNumber,
   OUT DWORD* pdwCoreTemp, //температура процессора
   OUT DWORD* pdwAmbientTemp,
   OUT DWORD* pdwUpperLimit);
```